# Stop PHP exception from escaping html

Tags: php, exception

I have a custom exception class, something like:

```php
class AwesomeException extends \Exception {

    public function __toString(){
        return "<strong>This is important!</strong>";
}
```

I then `throw new \AwesomeException("Blah blah");`
& instead of showing:

**This is important!**

in bold,

The output includes:

```html
<strong>This is Important!</strong>
```

When I view source, I see:

```html
&lt;strong&gt;This is Important!&lt;/strong&gt;
```

I tried overriding `getMessage()`, but that's final so it doesn't work.

I could have a global try/catch with custom output, something like:

```php
try {
    //do all of the things
}
catch (\Exception $e){
    echo $e;
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

But I'd really like `throw $e` to print the original `__toString` with html, rather than escaping things. I'd like the `AwesomeException` class to enforce this somehow.

I can also `echo` html from inside my `__toString()`, but that breaks the expectation of `__toString()`

I'm in PHP 7.4

#### EDIT

I'm thinking this might be apache? My `.htaccess` routes to a `deliver.php` file, so I've written the very start of the file to be:

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class AwesomeException extends \Exception {
    
    public function __toString(){
        return "<strong>This is important!</strong>";
    }
}

throw new \AwesomeException();


echo 'done throwing';

exit;
```

And I get the output source:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught &lt;strong&gt;This is important!&lt;/strong&gt;
  thrown in <b>/path/to/file/deliver.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

Comment: as-is it works https://3v4l.org/CRrRp you must be htmlentities'ing it when displaying it

Comment: If you're using a library like Laravel or similar, they will escape the output if you use `{{ $message }}`. But out of the box, as you have it now, there's no escaping of the string, as verified above by Lawrence.

Comment: Could it be something Apache is doing? @LawrenceCherone is right & when I run the php script through CLI, it's not escaping. But when I run it on my localhost server it is. I use my own framework & don't think I globally catch exceptions anywhere, but I'm looking.

Comment: Note that `echo $e` does NOT escape, but `throw $e` does

Comment: I really fail to see the difference. Can you recreate your example in a fiddle online? AFAIK there's no Apache setting or anything that escapes it. But if you have some custom exception handling in your own framework, then its impossible for us to answer the question without seeing how you're doing that.

Comment: I've taken the framework out of the equation, as the only thing running is this first bit of code that I just added to my question... I doubt I can recreate it in a fiddle...

Comment: Are you using XDebug or something similar? That will convert the error into htmlentities. Considering even "Fatal Error" is bolded, something is formatting and converting your error

Comment: Turns out [`html_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors) directive was the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `phpinfo()` & did ctrl+f for 'error', 'exception', 'htmlentities' & a couple others and ended up finding the [`html_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors) directive.

So I:

```php
ini_set('html_errors',0);
```

And now my html in exceptions is being printed unescaped. It no longer bolds my file name or "Fatal Error", though.